# Password policy to support random password generators like lastpass

Tags: passwords

I want to have a password policy that is supported by most of the password managers and generators like LastPass and chrome's password generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep registration and login as simple as possible, follow web accessibility guidelines, and don't have a password policy.

[Bruce Schneider summed up the latest NIST password best practices.](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2017/10/changes_in_pass.html)

1. Don't have password rules, they'll just interfere with generated passwords.

   - NIST: "Do not impose other composition rules (e.g. mixtures of
     different character types) on memorized secrets."
   - NIST: "Encourage users to make memorized secrets as lengthy as they want, using any characters they like (including spaces), thus aiding memorization."
   - NIST: "Allow at least 64 characters in length to support the use of passphrases."
2. Don't expire passwords.

   - NIST: "Do not require that memorized secrets be changed arbitrarily
     (e.g., periodically) unless there is a user request or evidence of
     authenticator compromise."
3. Make sure you're compatible with a password manager.

That last one means don't do anything special with registration and login. Basically follow [guidelines for web accessibility](https://www.wuhcag.com/).

- Use an HTML form with standard inputs
- Use `<label>`
- Use text or email type for username input
- Use password type for the password
- Use obvious names for your inputs
- NIST: "Support copy and paste functionality in fields for entering memorized secrets, including passphrases."
- Don't dynamically alter the form
- Don't change the names and ids
- Make sure the form renders on page load

And test your registration and login with a few popular password mangers. Don't forget mobile!

See also

- [1Password's recommendations](https://support.1password.com/compatible-website-design/)
- [Making password managers play ball with your login form](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2018-01-13-making-password-managers-play-ball-with-your-login-form)
- [Web Accessibility For Developers](https://www.wuhcag.com/)
- [NIST Special Publication 800-63B Digital Identity Guidelines Authentication and Lifecycle Management](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf) Section 10.2.1 "Memorized Secrets"